# Invocar clique e submissão de uma página

Tags: php, html, formulário-submeter

Não vou postar código na pergunta pois não sei o começo. Tenho uma página em HTML e com quero saber se é possível, com PHP invocar ação de clique, etc, em seletores por exemplo `.classe#id`.

Exemplo:

```
<body>
    <button id='go'>Meu botão 1</button>
    <button id='ex'>Meu botão 2</button>
</body>
```

Em um PHP externo é possível solicitar o clique em `button#go` ou `button#ex`? Se sim, como?

Comment: Resposta imediata: não. Click é um evento do DOM, e o PHP, por ser um pré processador, não interage com o DOM após a criação da página, como faz Javascript, por exemplo. É possível com PHP escrever uma função Javascript para manipular o DOM.

Comment: Você pode com Javascript, inclusive, executar algum código PHP (ajax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pesquisando e encontrando mais termos para a pesquisa, achei bibliotecas que fazem isso, como é o caso da [*Goutte*](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte), além disso o *SimpleTest* tem uma ferramenta parecida, etc, normalmente é voltado para teste funcional/teste de sistema.

Answer (score 1):

O PHP não faz isso, mas é possível fazer o PHP chamar quem faz - JavaScript com JQuery.

O PHP é executado no servidor, o clique acontece no cliente - no navegador.

O que pode fazer é o PHP gerar um código JavaScript que faça o evento do clique.

```
<script>
    <?php if ($habilita_clique_go) { ?>
        $('#go').click();
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($habilita_clique_ex) { ?>
        $('#ex').click();
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```